# How to Add multiple JComponents via .txt file

Tags: java, swing, file-io

I'm trying to create a program which will create several `JComponent` which are read from a *.txt* file.

For example if a *.txt* file contains the following:

```
"[JButton]
 OK~150~250~100~50
 Cancel~250~250~100~50"
```

Two JButtons should be created. One with the text "OK" in the position x(150),y(250) and size of 100 50 and the other with the text "Cancel" in the position x(250),y(250) and size of 100 50.

My problem is that it only creates one button. How can I add another button?

I tried to do a `do while` loop on the `if(s.equals="[JButton]")` part. Here's my code:

```
private void btnThreeActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    String filename="ButtonThreeComponent.txt";
    JFrame frame=new JFrame();
    JPanel panel=new JPanel();
    try (BufferedReader fw = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(filename))))
    {
        String s = null;
        while((s = fw.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            if(s.equals("[JFrame]"))
            {
                String property=fw.readLine();
                String infos[]=property.split("~");
                frame=new JFrame(infos[0]);
                frame.setLocation(Integer.parseInt(infos[1]), Integer.parseInt(infos[2]));
                frame.setSize(Integer.parseInt(infos[3]),Integer.parseInt(infos[4]));
                frame.setVisible(true);
                panel=new JPanel();
                panel.setLayout(null);
                frame.add(panel);
            }
            if(s.equals("[JTextField]"))
            {
                String property=fw.readLine();
                String infos[]=property.split("~");
                JTextField textfield=new JTextField(infos[0]);
                textfield.setSize(Integer.parseInt(infos[3]),Integer.parseInt(infos[4]));
                textfield.setLocation(Integer.parseInt(infos[1]), Integer.parseInt(infos[2]));
                panel.add(textfield);

            }
            if(s.equals("[JButton]"))
            {
                    while((property=fw.readLine())!=null)
                {
                    String[] infos=property.split("~");
                    JButton button=new JButton(infos[0]);
                    button.setSize(Integer.parseInt(infos[3]),Integer.parseInt(infos[4]));
                    button.setLocation(Integer.parseInt(infos[1]), Integer.parseInt(infos[2]));
                    panel.add(button);
                }

            }

            if(s.equals("[JLabel]"))
            {
                String property=fw.readLine();
                String infos[]=property.split("~");
                JLabel label=new JLabel(infos[0]);
                label.setSize(Integer.parseInt(infos[3]),Integer.parseInt(infos[4]));
                label.setLocation(Integer.parseInt(infos[1]), Integer.parseInt(infos[2]));
                panel.add(label);
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because in this line : `while(fw.readLine()!=null);` you read value and you do nothing with it, so it is lost.

If you add 3rows of buttons, probably the third one will appear, because second one will be lost and the third one will be loaded into `String property=fw.readLine();`

Comment: Well then you have multiple errors (but this one I mention still exists), does it throw any error?

Comment: I updated the code and the button now shows... but now it throws an ArrayIndexOutofBounds exception...